# Lucene locking exceptions

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, lucene

I'm load testing a webservice which writes to a lucene index. If I make the same call repeatedly I get a

```
org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException:
```

I assume this is because I'm trying to write to an index which is already locked by another thread and that thread waits.

My question is, what is the best way to solve this problem? Do I increase the waiting time or add the write requests to a queue?

Please advise, thanks.

Comment: Does this happen after you have redeployed the webapp?

Comment: The locks are released after the writer is done. There are just too many writes going to the one index, that they're timing out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you have multiple writers? IndexWriter is inherently thread-safe; you should have all your threads accessing the same writer. This will get rid of your locking issues.

Comment: Yes, I'm now queuing all my threads to the same writer. Thanks.